# CSS transform scale with flex-direction column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use CSS `transform: scale(1.5);` within a flex container. I need the `hidden` content to be displayed above and centered to the original text, so to do this I am using `flex-direction: column;` which works.

The issue is when the `transform` executes, the sibling html element grows too. (You can see the behavior within the code snippet)

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I've tried several solutions can't figure out why this is happening. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-action="clickable"]').mousedown(function(item) {
    $(item.currentTarget).addClass('flex-item-blowout');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.hidden').addClass('displayed');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  });

  $('[data-action="clickable"]').mouseup(function(item) {
    $(item.currentTarget).removeClass('flex-item-blowout');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').addClass('hidden');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').removeClass('displayed');
  });

  $('[data-action="clickable"]').mouseleave(function(item) {
    $(item.currentTarget).removeClass('flex-item-blowout');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').addClass('hidden');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').removeClass('displayed');
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: burlywood;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.flex-item-blowout {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: coral;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" data-action="clickable">
    <span class="hidden">2</span><span>1 + 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-action="clickable">
    <span class="hidden">3</span><span>1 + 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The reason this happens is because when you click an element, it first displays the _hidden_ `span`, which cause the `flex-item` to increase its height to accommodate the displayed element's content, and as _flex row items_ on the same row will stretch to fit its parent, the none clicked element will adjust. If you remove the `transform` you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `align-items: flex-start` to the `.flex-container`, which will prevent the *default* behavior of the value `stretch`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-action="clickable"]').mousedown(function(item) {
    $(item.currentTarget).addClass('flex-item-blowout');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.hidden').addClass('displayed');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
  });

  $('[data-action="clickable"]').mouseup(function(item) {
    $(item.currentTarget).removeClass('flex-item-blowout');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').addClass('hidden');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').removeClass('displayed');
  });

  $('[data-action="clickable"]').mouseleave(function(item) {
    $(item.currentTarget).removeClass('flex-item-blowout');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').addClass('hidden');
    $(item.currentTarget).find('.displayed').removeClass('displayed');
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row;
  line-height: 30px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.flex-item {
  background: burlywood;
  color: white;
  margin: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  min-width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  user-select: none;
}

.flex-item-blowout {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: coral;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item" data-action="clickable">
    <span class="hidden">2</span><span>1 + 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item" data-action="clickable">
    <span class="hidden">3</span><span>1 + 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't put this in my original snippet, but if you have another `flex-container` after this one, it will 'bump' it down with `align-items: flex-start;` set. It's almost like it adds padding or margin to the `flex-container`.

Comment: @shakin No, it simply adjust the `flex-item`'s height for both `span` to fit. I believe you think the `transform` should simply _scale_ it, though that is not how `transform` work. `transform` doesn't change the original flow, it _transform_ the element visually, so any change made to the element or its content will still apply.

Comment: OK, that helps. It appears then that the `align-items` won't work in this case since I'm adding a span. I was able to work around this by adding a `height: 56px` to the `flex-container` and top and bottom padding for the `flex-item-blowout` to make it look better.